# Restarted my Ubuntu Touch Nexus 4 and now my cellular network access is denied but works with another carrier's SIM card

Tags: ubuntu-touch, connection, nexus-4

I installed Ubuntu Touch about 2 months ago on my Nexus 4 following these instructions:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

I unlocked my device and connected it to the computer and installed using the following command:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09 --bootstrap
```

Everything has been working fine until Monday afternoon when I restarted the phone and could no longer connect to my cellular network. I am using WIND Mobile and I live in Toronto.

In the network settings under the cellular section, where it would display the network name and connection strength, instead it just says "Denied" with a blank connection status (or 0 bars of connectivity; the triangle outline).

I have tried restarting and powering off, and leaving the phone off for a day, etc. nothing has seemed to work. I swapped out SIM cards with my Mom who is with Fido and her sim card connects to her network perfectly.

I also tried my house-mates SIM (he is with Koodo) and he got the same thing, his network is Denied.

I have also tried my WIND sim card in other phones and it has no issue connecting to my network.

I know that Koodo, WIND, Mobilicity, etc. use the same range of frequencies to connect

And that Bell, Rogers, Fido use a different range of frequencies.

It seems that a recent update or something for Ubuntu Touch has given it an error in connecting to the frequency ranges for Koodo/WIND/etc. while the frequencies for the big wig companies are unaffected.

What can I do about this? My ubuntu phone has become unusable.

```
phablet@ubuntu:~$ system-image-cli -i
current build number: 12
device name: mako
channel: ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09
last update: 1969-12-31
version version: 12
version ubuntu: 20141218
version device: 20141119
version custom: mako-1.1
```

My phone says it is up to date. Please let me know if I can provide any more information or how I can troubleshoot this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with the guys in the #ubuntu-touch freenode irc channel I eventually flashed my Nexus 4 back to android and connected to my mobile network. The Ubuntu Touch guys believe this caused a radio fw update. I was then able to reflash and reinstall the latest stable version of Ubuntu Touch and reconnect to my mobile network. Definitely not an ideal situation but at least I am connected again and I don't have to use Android or iOS.